# increment and decrement the time and loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

if my time is 12:00am and i want to display as

11:30pm 11:45pm 12:00am 12:15am 12:30am
please help me for getting this iam learning now

```
$i= $_GET['time'] 

$start=strtotime($i);
$end=strtotime('2:30');

for ($i=$start;$i<=$end;$i = $i + 15*60) {
   echo date('H:i A',$i).'<br>';
}
```

iam getting result as

00:00 AM

00:15 AM

00:30 AM

00:45 AM

01:00 AM

01:15 AM

01:30 AM

01:45 AM

02:00 AM

02:15 AM

02:30 AM

Comment: For a start, I feel using [DateTime](http://php.net/DateTime) would be simpler. As for the rest, is your question how t o get the previous 2 quarter hours? With DateTime you would just `sub` 30 mins, then loop around `add`ing 15 until you hit the limit.

Comment: could u please give me the code iam unable to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```html
<?php

$i= '12:00 am';
$start=strtotime("-30 minutes" , strtotime($i));
$end=strtotime("+30 minutes" , strtotime($i));

for ($i=$start;$i<=$end;$i = $i + 15*60) 
{
    echo "<br/>";
   echo date('h:i A',$i).'<br>';
}

?>
```

Comment: you can change $i= '12:00 am' to $i= $_GET['time']

Answer (score 0):

use

```
echo date('h:i a',$i).'<br>';
```

for more details use reference [php date time class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: i think u did not read my question. You have answered the same from my code, I want to display as 11:30pm 11:45pm 12:00am 12:15am 12:30am

Comment: Bro use small `h` instead of the capital one `H`

Comment: the output is this 12:00 AM
12:15 AM
12:30 AM
12:45 AM
01:00 AM
01:15 AM
01:30 AM
01:45 AM
02:00 AM
02:15 AM
02:30 AM . i want to get as this 11:30pm 11:45pm 12:00am 12:15am 12:30am

Comment: use date('h:i a',$i);

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$time_interval = $time->reservation_time_interval; //if 15 min
$dateTime = new DateTime($_GET['date'].$_GET['time']); //if 12:00 am
$dateTime->modify("-$time_interval min");
$date_pre= $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
$time_pre= $dateTime->format('h:i a');

$dateTime = new DateTime($time_pre);
$dateTime->modify("-$time_interval min");
$time_pre1= $dateTime->format('h:i a');

$dateTime = new DateTime($_GET['time']);
$dateTime->modify("$time_interval min");
$time_post= $dateTime->format('h:i a');

$dateTime = new DateTime($time_post);
$dateTime->modify("$time_interval min");
$time_post1= $dateTime->format('h:i a');

echo $time_pre;echo $time_pre1;echo $time_post;echo $time_post;
?>
```

when u print, u will get this=
11:30pm 11:45pm 12:15am 12:30am